# Create custom UI bar button (to change view from list view, grid view)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibarbuttonitem

I am trying to create ui bar button like this to change view.

[image]

However, I don't know how to do to put 2 ui bar buttom together (1 square button and 4 square button). I only know how to do something like this. How should I do?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is `UISegmentedControl` not `UIButton`

```
UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] init];
[segmentedControl insertSegmentWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"0.png"] atIndex:0 animated:NO];
[segmentedControl insertSegmentWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"] atIndex:1 animated:NO];
UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:segmentedControl];
[[[self navigationController] navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItem:barButtonItem];
```